# How to use gnuplot to draw a bar chart, and color it using the 'accent' color palette?

Tags: gnuplot

data.txt

| cola | colb |
| --- | --- |
| name a | 60 |
| name b | 55 |
| name c | 10 |

```
cola colb
namea 60
nameb 55
namec 10
```

this is my code.

```
set linetype 1  lc rgb '#7FC97F' # pale green
set linetype 2  lc rgb '#BEAED4' # pale purple
set linetype 3  lc rgb '#FDC086' # pale orange

set boxwidth 0.8 relative
set style fill solid border 

plot 'data.txt' using 0:2:($0+1):xtic(1) w boxes lc var
```

I want to know if there is any other more concise way?
like

```
load "accent.pal" #load accent palette
plot 'data.txt' w boxes lc accent
```

I get `accent.pal` from [Gnuplotting/gnuplot-palettes](https://github.com/Gnuplotting/gnuplot-palettes)

=====New ======

1 with set key autotitle columnhead
[image: setkey]

2 no set key autotitle columnhead
[image: nosetkey]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You have been pretty close.

**Short answer:**

```
plot 'data.txt' u 0:2:0:xtic(1) w boxes lc palette
```

You have to be aware that the palette `accent.pal` uses 8 colors and no grading in between them (`set palette maxcolors 8`).

`$0` (basically the row number) will determine the color and the values will set `cbrange`.
If you only have 3 data points, the colors will be taken equidistant from palette. If you want row 1 to get the first color and row N the Nth color you have to fix your `cbrange` to the number of colors in the palette, i.e.`cbrange[1:8]`.

**Script:**

```
### load palette from external file
reset session

$Data <<EOD
cola colb
namea 60
nameb 55
namec 10
EOD

set boxwidth 0.8 relative
set style fill solid border 
set yrange[0:]

set cbrange[1:8]
# unset colorbox     # uncomment if you want to remove the colorbox
load "accent.pal"    # load accent palette

plot $Data u 0:2:0:xtic(1) w boxes lc palette notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank Yo very much.  I still have one place that I don't understand. When adding 'set key autotitle columnhead' (I use this command to ignore the first line of the txt file), the colors of namea and nameb become the same. What is the reason for this? I have posted the picture in the above post

Comment: @AndyAdam with using columnheader, `namea` becomes row 0 and `nameb` becomes row 1. Apparently, row 0 in `cbrange[1:8]` will be plotted with the same color as row 1. You can correct this with `plot $Data u 0:2:($0+1):xtic(1) w boxes lc palette`.